# connection.play() is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a music bot. It joins the channel and the song search is also working but it won't play it. I have tried with .playFile but it still doesn't work. I saw a post where they said you need await when you declare the connection but it doesn't work here. I'm a beginner so sorry if the question is stupid :D

```
 const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const Discord=require('discord.js')
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { getVoiceConnection } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                guildId: message.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
            })
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection =  joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
        
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
               voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Check the docs and see if `joinVoiceChannel` returns a promise, If applicable resolve it. 2) Check the docs to see the method name for playing. Simply looking at the documentation for whatever you're using can make a difference

Comment: In the docs there is the .play() function. But how do I seeif it returns a promise?